# Jquery with HTTPS

Tags: jquery, http, https

When I  run my code on HTTP Internet Explorer browser it works fine. But when I try to run the same code on HTTPS  I do not get result as expected .

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {        
        alert("here");              
        $.post('process.php', {name:'test1',email:'test.com'}, function(data)
        {
            $('#results').html(data);
            alert(data);
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do get an alert box saying HERE along with an Ok button. but the problem is when I click on that OK button I do not get anything. Ideally I should be getting another alert box.

Could please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check Console and Network in the Webdeveloper Tools (F12).

Comment: If you run a more explicit `$.ajax` call you can add in the error callback and it has more information about what went wrong passed into it.

Comment: Check the headers in the console in Chrome, look for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin option. This will in some cases allow https to work like it should, but since it's not supported by Internet Explorer and Opera as far as I know, it will not work in those browsers. Only thing I can think of?

Comment: @adeneo is there no solution for this then ?

Comment: There's always a solution, just not sure what it is ?

Comment: I checked in opera and its working in it

Comment: @adeneo I found out the answer .

The solution is to  include an header file

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer .

```
The solution is to  include an header file
```

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");